# MDX calculated member regardless of selectors

Tags: mdx

I have an MDX script like;

`select
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Miktar Kg]} ON COLUMNS
,
NON EMPTY 
[DimSalesRepView].[SalesRepName].[SalesRepName]*
[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT ([DimDateView].[Year].&[2016]}) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( [DimCompanyView].[CompanyKey].&[smr]) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model]))`

And I can get desired results. What I would like to achieve is defining another calculated Measure which will show [Miktar Kg] for all times, regardless of selectors, where filters etc. Like;

`-      -   Miktar Kg   AllTimesMiktarKg
SELIM   1   8089259         27499099
SELIM   2   2591473         27499099
YASAR   1   11384002        27499099
YASAR   2   5434365         27499099`

And I have to do this within script, not in cube.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe just add a tuple for `All` this will add a row:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Miktar Kg]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [DimSalesRepView].[SalesRepName].[SalesRepName]
      * 
        [DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
     ,(
        [DimSalesRepView].[SalesRepName].[All]
       ,[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[All]
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [DimDateView].[Year].&[2016] ON 0
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      [DimCompanyView].[CompanyKey].&[smr] ON 0
    FROM [Model]
  )
);
```

To add a column for total you need to make a calculated member using a `WITH` clause:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AllTimesMiktarKg] AS
      (
        [DimSalesRepView].[SalesRepName].[All]
       ,[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[All]
       ,[Measures].[Miktar Kg]
      )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Miktar Kg]
     ,[Measures].[AllTimesMiktarKg] 
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
        [DimSalesRepView].[SalesRepName].[SalesRepName]
      * [DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
     ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [DimDateView].[Year].&[2016] ON 0
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      [DimCompanyView].[CompanyKey].&[smr] ON 0
    FROM [Model]
  )
);
```